I'm looking for an IF functionality
I am looking to create and IF function that does the following.
There is a ton of data with one column containing dates. I want and if functions that labels each row according to the following.
If date falls between 7 days of a certain date on a different column then label "on time" (so if date on column A stated 20/11/2024 and on a column B stated 27/11/2024 then it should be labelled as "on time". Should column B falls on 28/11/2024 and/or onward, it should be labelled as "late")
Hope someone can help.
Many thanks
An automatic and functional formula that connect 2 different column

Have you made any attempts so far? Or some research? Try sharing some sample/mock data using a Markdown table generator, in text-form.

This requires a basic formula, e.g., =IF((B2-A2)>7,"late","on time"). To cover invalid (smaller) dates, you could improve with =IF((B2-A2)>7,"late",IF((B2-A2)>=0,"on time","invalid")).

@VBasic2008 small point:  B2<A2 can replace (B2-A2)>=0.  I had separately come up with essentially the same thing using Let() because I prefer the visual (adding breaks for each variable/formula, alt+enter):  =LET( myDate,B1, tarDate,A1, IF(myDate<tarDate,"Invalid",IF((tarDate+7)<myDate,"Late","On-Time")) )

Clarifications: you say "between 7 days of a certain date on a different column".  Is this in both directions, or only afterwards?  (i.e. if Column A said 2024-11-20, then is the "On Time" range from 2024-11-20 to 2024-11-27, or is it from 2024-11-13 to 2024-11-27?)  And, in either case: what should happen if Column B falls before the "On Time" range? (e.g. 2024-11-10)
